# why does my aggregate ($lookup) function does not work in mongoose and node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my `mongoose` database I have two models: `Users` and `Comments`.

In my `node.js` code I have:

```
var Comment = require('./../models/commentsModel.js');
var User = require('./../models/usersModel.js');
```

Now I want to construct a query with `$lookup` to return results from `Comments` and corresponding `Users` (currently `Comments` contain a field `user_id`). This is what I have so far:

```
function executeQuery(query, callback) {
    query = Comment.find(query);

    Comment.aggregate([{$lookup:
    { from: "users",
        localField: "user_id",
        foreignField:"_id",
        as: "user"
    }}]);

    query.exec(function(err, comments){
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
    return callback(null, comments);
    });
}
```

but I do not see any data from `User` attached to the results from `Comment`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing your aggregation query. Either add a function callback at the end or call `exec(function(err,res))` :

```
Comment.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "user_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user"
    }
}],function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Or

```
var aggregateQuery = Comment.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "user_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user"
    }
}]);
aggregateQuery.exec(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
})
```